# Find the number which the given equation is true

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the number which the given equation is true
$$\overline{abcd}=a^a+b^b+c^c+d^d$$

Comment: I assume $\overline{abcd}$ is $1000a+100b+10c+d$ where $a,b,c,d \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Is that correct?

Comment: yes abcd is a four digit number

Comment: Is it OK if we have leading digits of $0$? For example, does $a=0$, $b=0$, $c=3$, and $d=0$ count as a solution if we say $0^0=1$ since $$a^a+b^b+c^c+d^d=0^0+0^0+3^3+0^0=1+1+27+1=30=0030$$

Comment: With a program I found that $3435$ is the only such number.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey That is true, but some people say $0^0=1$ in the case of these problems.

Comment: For crying out loud: $b,c,d \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $a \in \{1,2,3,4\}$. Still there are many cases left to examine. Even if a solution using pen-paper is found, I doubt of its efficiacy as compared to a one using code.

Comment: @Roby5 I'm writing a solution by hand right now. I think there are more cases to be eliminated.

Answer (score 4):

We have the following:
$$0^0=1$$
$$1^1=1$$
$$2^2=4$$
$$3^3=27$$
$$4^4=256$$
$$5^5=3125$$
$$6^6=46656$$
At this point, this is too big for $4$-digit numbers, so we know that we can only use $0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Let's take $5$ out of the situation for a second. Now, the biggest we could possible have is $4^4+4^4+4^4+4^4=1024$. That's clearly not a solution, so we know it has to be less than $1000$. This means $a=0$. If we try $0444$, we get a $7$, so that's not right. If we try $044X$ for $X \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, we get a $5$, so that's not right. If we try $04XX$, we need to get the $4^4=256$ up to $300$ in order to get rid of the big tens digit, so we need $0433$. However, $0^0+4^4+3^3+3^3=310 \neq 433$, so that's not a solution.

Therefore, we find that if we don't use $5$, we also can't use $4$. Thus, the biggest solution we can have is $0333$ which yields $0^0+3^3+3^3+3^3=81$, which is less than $100$. Therefore, we only need to check $00XX$ for $X \in \{0,1,2,3\}$. We know that the answer is at least $0^0+0^0+0^0+0^0=4$, so to get rid of the big ones-digit, we need to have an answer above $10$. Therefore, we need to use a $3$. If we test $003X$ for $X \in \{0,1,2\}$, the only solution we get is $0^0+0^0+3^3+0^0=0030$.

Now, let's use $5$. There's no way we have more than one $5$ since that leads to more than a $4$-digit number or a big thousands digit. Therefore, our biggest solution is $5444$. However, $5^5+4^4+4^4+4^4$ is between $3000$ and $4000$, so we know that the leading digit has to be $3$. This makes our biggest solution $3544$, so we get $3^3+5^5+4^4+4^4=3664$. This is too big, meaning we can only have one $4$ or no $4$s. If we try $354X$ for $X \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, the only solution we get is $3^3+5^5+4^4+3^3=3435$.

Now, for solutions without a $4$, the biggest case is $3533$ for which we get $3^3+5^5+3^3+3^3=3206$ which is not a solution, so we know it has to be less than $3200$, but still more than $3^3+5^5=3152$. We need the tens digit to be $5$ or less, so we get that the solution needs to be between $3152$ and $3160$. If we test $315X$ for $X \in \{0,1,2,3\}$, we get no solutions.

Thus, our only solutions are $0030$ and $3435$.

Comment: $0^0$ is not always defined. Sometimes it's $1$, sometimes it's left undefined. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0) chooses not to define it.

Comment: @user236182 If you want to exclude $0$ from the problem entirely, then simply ignore the $0030$ solution. This simplifies the case where we exclude $5$ extremely because once we figure out that $a=0$, we abandon that case immediately and realize we need a $5$. However, I included $0^0=1$ because I thought the problem would be too easy if we just ignored it.

Answer (score 3):

$a,b,c,d\le 5$ because $5^5=3125$ and $6^6=46656$ (five digits).

$\boxed {a=5}$

$$ 5000+100b+10c+d=3125+b^b+c^c+d^d\\1875+100b+10c+d=b^b+c^c+d^d$$ Hence $b,c,d\lt 5$ and since $3\cdot4^4=768$ there is no solution.

$\boxed{a=4}$

$$4000+100b+10c+d=256+b^b+c^c+d^d\\3744+100b+10c+d=b^b+c^c+d^d$$ Necessarily  one of $b,c,d$ is equal to $5$ because $3\cdot4^4=768$; it follows $619+100b+10c+d=x^x+y^y\le 2\cdot 4^4=512$ then there is no solution.

$\boxed{a=3}$

We have $$2973+100b+10c+d=b^b+c^c+d^d$$ Necessarily one of $b,c,d$ must be equal to $5$ so we have $$100b+10c+d=x^x+y^y+152\\x^x+y^y\le 555-152=403\lt2\cdot4^4=512$$ Hence we have to test $(x,y)$ with $x\le 4$ and $y\le 4$. The only solution  is $(x,y)=(4,3),(3,4)$ which gives $5^5+4^4+3^3+3^3=3435$ in accordance with the request by the post.

$\boxed{a=2}$ and $\boxed{a=1}$ are trivially discarded.

Thus the  only solution turns out  to be $\color{red}{3435}$

Comment: can you explain $3*4^4$ and $2*4^4$

Comment: For the case $a=5$, you have $1875+100b+10c+d=b^b+c^c+d^d$ and $b,c,d\lt 5$. Hence the maximun possible for $b^b+c^c+d^d$ is $4^4+4^4+4^4=3*4^4=768\lt 1875$. Thus NO solution. (For $2*4^4$ similar reasoning).